# How do I invalidate cache in few specific time in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I know I can use `tag` to invalidate the RTK query cache for auto refetching, but how can I set a specific time to do the auto refetching?

For example, I have a `getPosts` with a tag `Posts`, how can I make the cache refresh automatically in 1 hour without calling any other actions like `addPost`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` or something similar to call `api.util.invalidateTags` manually.

```js
setTimeout(
  () => {
    dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(["Banana", "Bread"]));
  },
  // ~ milliseconds left in the hour
  (60 - new Date().getMinutes()) * 60 * 1000
);
```

Comment: The author of the post and me probably are looking for similar solution, and your proposal seems to do the job, but where to put it? Is there a kind of middleware to put this when app starts, or cache invalidation parameter in store endpoints config?

I need to do the check when: App starts, when user stays on a page long, when they open page again after some time. 3 different cases, which need to be tackled in one place ideally.

Comment: @Rantiev It's really up to you. Maybe in the line after creating the api?

Comment: Yep, did that, and got the other issue, as looks like action is sync, there is chrome console callback took much time violation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352132/how-to-make-async-rtk-action-in-setinterval